# Create partitioned with move partitioned data from original table

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I have big size of database almost 500GB and i just wanted to retain 1 years of data from some large tables and move others data to a different location, So I am trying this by creating partitions on table by date and time. After creating the partition, I can see the partitioned schema in the storage folder and I can also see the original data in the main table. Is there any way to move the data from the original table while creating a partition or only option is to archive the data. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Please don't multi-post the same question to multiple sites. Pick one. If it's the wrong one, it will get migrated. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210843/create-partitioned-with-move-partitioned-data-from-original-table

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is also posted on the DBA site.